# Selecting text from multiple textViews at the same time

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm trying to show a long text (like a book) in a screen in iOS. It will be scrolled vertically. And the text should be selectable by the user.

I think putting the whole text in a single textView will not be a good approach (for memory reasons). So I decided to divide it into pages and put it in a tableView. Every row has a textView with a single page of text.

This seems OK so far. But when the user tries to select text from multiple pages, the textView stops selection at the end of the upper page.

Is there a way to select text from different textViews at the same time?
Or should I try another way?

I need something like this:

[image: I need something like this]

I tried putting the text in a UILabel but it's not selectable. Also I don't want to use UIPageViewController for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I couldn't find a direct way for selecting text from separate textViews.

But there may be a workaround:

1. The long-click gesture (which starts the text selection) is listened with a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and the beginning of the selected text is defined by this way.
2. The word at the point of tap is highlighted via `NSAttributedString`.
3. Two `UIImageView`s with cursor images are added as subviews and settled at the beginning and end points of highlighted text.
4. TapRecognizers are added to the both cursor views.
5. When a cursor view is tapped and dragged, the highlighted text is renewed accordingly.

This method is probably an expensive way, but it may offer an idea for the future.